# PingPong en C para 2 jugadores

Tags: c

**Buenas, tengo un código de Ping Pong hecho en c con ayuda de YouTube, la cosa es que no se como puedo hacer para que funcione para 2 jugadores, por el momento funciona para un jugador dejo a continuación el código sin modificar**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define V 21
#define H 75

int main(){
    
    int pelX, pelY, iniJUG, finJUG, iniIA, finIA;
    int modX, modY, modIA;
    char campo[V][H];
    
    pelX = 37;
    pelY = 10;
    
    iniJUG = 8;
    finJUG = 12;
    
    iniIA = 8;
    finIA = 12;
    
    modX = -1;
    modY = -1;
    modIA = -1;
    
    inicio(campo, pelX, pelY, iniJUG, finJUG, iniIA, finIA);
    GameLoop(campo, pelX, pelY, iniJUG, finJUG, iniIA, finIA, modX, modY, modIA);
    gotoxy(0,0);
    return 0;
}

void inicio(char campo[V][H],int pelX, int pelY, int iniJUG, int finJUG, int iniIA, int finIA){
    borde(campo);
    raquetaJUG(campo, iniJUG, finJUG);
    raquetaIA(campo, iniIA, finIA);
    pelota(campo, pelX, pelY);
}

void borde(char campo[V][H]){
    
    int i, j;
    
    for (i = 0; i < V; i++){
        
        for (j = 0; j < H; j++){
            if (i == 0 || i == V - 1){
                campo[i][j] = '-';
            }
            else if (j == 0 || j == H - 1){
                campo[i][j] = '|';
            }
            else{
                campo[i][j] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
    
}

void raquetaJUG(char campo[V][H], int iniJUG, int finJUG){
    
    int i, j;
    
    for (i = iniJUG; i <= finJUG; i++){
        for (j = 2; j <= 3; j++){
            campo[i][j] = 'X'; // RAQUETA JUGADOR
        }
    }   
}

void raquetaIA(char campo[V][H], int iniIA, int finIA){
    
    int i, j;
    
    for (i = iniIA; i <= finIA; i++){
        for (j = H - 4; j <= H - 3; j++){
            campo [i][j] = 'X'; //RAQUETA IA
        }
    }
}

void pelota(char campo[V][H], int pelX, int pelY){
    
    campo[pelY][pelX] = 'O';
    
}

void MostrarCampo(char campo[V][H]){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < V; i++){
        
        for(j = 0; j < H; j++){
            printf("%c" , campo[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
}

void GameLoop(char campo[V][H],int pelX, int pelY, int iniJUG, int finJUG, int iniIA, int finIA, int modX, int modY, int modIA){
    
    int gol;
    gol = 0;
    
    do{
        draw(campo); //DIBUJAR EN PANTALLA
        input(campo, &pelX, &pelY, &iniJUG, &finJUG, &iniIA, &finIA, &modX, &modY, &modIA, &gol); //MODIFICAR POSICIONES
        update(campo, pelX, pelY, iniJUG, finJUG, iniIA, finIA);//ACTUALIZAR CAMPO

    }while(gol == 0);
    
}

void draw(char campo[V][H]){
    gotoxy(0,0);
    MostrarCampo(campo);
}

void input(char campo[V][H],int *pelX, int *pelY, int *iniJUG, int *finJUG, int *iniIA, int *finIA, int *modX, int *modY, int *modIA, int *gol){
    int i;
    char key;
    //verificacion
    
    if (*pelY == 1 || *pelY == V - 2){
        *modY *= -1;
    }
    if (*pelX == 1 || *pelX == H - 2){
        *gol = 1;
    }
    if (*pelX == 4){
        
        for(i = (*iniJUG); i <= (*finJUG); i++){
            if (i == (*pelY)){
                *modX *= -1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (*pelX == H - 5){
        for (i = (*iniIA); i <= (*finIA); i++){
            if (i == (*pelY)){
                *modX *= -1;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (*iniIA == 1 || *finIA == V - 1){
        *modIA *= -1;
    }
    //modificacion
    if(*gol == 0){
        //pelota
        *pelX += (*modX);
        *pelY += (*modY);
        //raqueta IA
        *iniIA += (*modIA);
        *finIA += (*modIA);
        
        if (kbhit() == 1){
            key = getch();
            
            if (key == 'w'){
                if (*iniJUG != 1){
                    *iniJUG -= 1;
                    *finJUG -= 1;
                }
            }
            if (key == 's'){
                if (*finJUG != V - 2){
                    *iniJUG += 1;
                    *finJUG += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
}

void update(char campo[V][H],int pelX, int pelY, int iniJUG, int finJUG, int iniIA, int finIA){
    borde(campo);
    raquetaJUG(campo, iniJUG, finJUG);
    raquetaIA(campo, iniIA, finIA);
    pelota(campo, pelX, pelY);
}


void gotoxy(int x, int y){ 
     COORD coord; 
     coord.X=x; 
     coord.Y=y; 
     SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),coord); 
}
```

****probé creando otra variable llamada key2 adentro de la función input y añadiendo esto:****

```
key2 = getch(); 
            if (key2 == 72){
                if (*iniIA != 1){
                    *iniIA -= 1;
                    *finIA -= 1;
                }
            }
            
            if (key2 == 80){
                if (*finJUG != V - 2){
                    *iniIA += 1;
                    *finIA += 1;
                }
            }
```

**esto de arriba va abajo de key = getch(); y arriba del if (key == 'w') pero el problema con esto es que el kbhit() deja de funcionar debido a que el getch del key y el getch del key 2 se interponen por decirlo así, entonces cuando compilamos el codigo la pelota se detiene. Dejo el código de como quedaría si unimos lo de arriba:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define V 21
#define H 75

int main(){
    
    int pelX, pelY, iniJUG, finJUG, iniIA, finIA;
    int modX, modY, modIA;
    char campo[V][H];
    
    pelX = 37;
    pelY = 10;
    
    iniJUG = 8;
    finJUG = 12;
    
    iniIA = 8;
    finIA = 12;
    
    modX = -1;
    modY = -1;
    modIA = -1;
    
    inicio(campo, pelX, pelY, iniJUG, finJUG, iniIA, finIA);
    GameLoop(campo, pelX, pelY, iniJUG, finJUG, iniIA, finIA, modX, modY, modIA);
    gotoxy(0,0);
    return 0;
}

void inicio(char campo[V][H],int pelX, int pelY, int iniJUG, int finJUG, int iniIA, int finIA){
    borde(campo);
    raquetaJUG(campo, iniJUG, finJUG);
    raquetaIA(campo, iniIA, finIA);
    pelota(campo, pelX, pelY);
}

void borde(char campo[V][H]){
    
    int i, j;
    
    for (i = 0; i < V; i++){
        
        for (j = 0; j < H; j++){
            if (i == 0 || i == V - 1){
                campo[i][j] = '-';
            }
            else if (j == 0 || j == H - 1){
                campo[i][j] = '|';
            }
            else{
                campo[i][j] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
    
}

void raquetaJUG(char campo[V][H], int iniJUG, int finJUG){
    
    int i, j;
    
    for (i = iniJUG; i <= finJUG; i++){
        for (j = 2; j <= 3; j++){
            campo[i][j] = 'X';
        }
    }   
}

void raquetaIA(char campo[V][H], int iniIA, int finIA){
    
    int i, j;
    
    for (i = iniIA; i <= finIA; i++){
        for (j = H - 4; j <= H - 3; j++){
            campo [i][j] = 'X';
        }
    }
}

void pelota(char campo[V][H], int pelX, int pelY){
    
    campo[pelY][pelX] = 'O';
    
}

void MostrarCampo(char campo[V][H]){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < V; i++){
        
        for(j = 0; j < H; j++){
            printf("%c" , campo[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
}

void GameLoop(char campo[V][H],int pelX, int pelY, int iniJUG, int finJUG, int iniIA, int finIA, int modX, int modY, int modIA){
    
    int gol;
    gol = 0;
    
    do{
        draw(campo); //DIBUJAR EN PANTALLA
        input(campo, &pelX, &pelY, &iniJUG, &finJUG, &iniIA, &finIA, &modX, &modY, &modIA, &gol); //MODIFICAR POSICIONES
        update(campo, pelX, pelY, iniJUG, finJUG, iniIA, finIA);//ACTUALIZAR CAMPO

    }while(gol == 0);
    
}

void draw(char campo[V][H]){
    gotoxy(0,0);
    MostrarCampo(campo);
}

void input(char campo[V][H],int *pelX, int *pelY, int *iniJUG, int *finJUG, int *iniIA, int *finIA, int *modX, int *modY, int *modIA, int *gol){
    int i;
    char key, key2;
    //verificacion
    
    if (*pelY == 1 || *pelY == V - 2){
        *modY *= -1;
    }
    if (*pelX == 1 || *pelX == H - 2){
        *gol = 1;
    }
    if (*pelX == 4){
        
        for(i = (*iniJUG); i <= (*finJUG); i++){
            if (i == (*pelY)){
                *modX *= -1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (*pelX == H - 5){
        for (i = (*iniIA); i <= (*finIA); i++){
            if (i == (*pelY)){
                *modX *= -1;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (*iniIA == 1 || *finIA == V - 1){
        *modIA *= -1;
    }
    //modificacion
    if(*gol == 0){
        //pelota
        *pelX += (*modX);
        *pelY += (*modY);


    
        if (kbhit() == 1){
            key = getch();  
            key2 = getch(); 
            if (key2 == 72){
                if (*iniIA != 1){
                    *iniIA -= 1;
                    *finIA -= 1;
                }
            }
            
            if (key2 == 80){
                if (*finJUG != V - 2){
                    *iniIA += 1;
                    *finIA += 1;
                }
            }
            
            if (key == 'w'){
                if (*iniJUG != 1){
                    *iniJUG -= 1;
                    *finJUG -= 1;
                }
            }
            if (key == 's'){
                if (*finJUG != V - 2){
                    *iniJUG += 1;
                    *finJUG += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
}

void update(char campo[V][H],int pelX, int pelY, int iniJUG, int finJUG, int iniIA, int finIA){
    borde(campo);
    raquetaJUG(campo, iniJUG, finJUG);
    raquetaIA(campo, iniIA, finIA);
    pelota(campo, pelX, pelY);
}


void gotoxy(int x, int y){ 
     COORD coord; 
     coord.X=x; 
     coord.Y=y; 
     SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),coord); 
}

void constante(){
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Y cual es la idea que quieres implementar. Como moveria el segundo jugador?

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola, voy a intentar ayudarte pero te aviso de que no va a ser sencillo!

Tú quieres crear un juego para dos jugadores. Tienes varias opciones pero te voy a comentar la más sencilla que se me ocurre.

Crea algo como
`If(pospelota() > mitad de campo) { //Activas el control de un jugador y desactivas el otro} else { //Desactivas el control de un jugador y activas el otro}`

De esta forma te aseguras que no se vuelva loco el buffer. Para eso, debes de conocer la posición de la pelota y saber si está en un lado o en otro del campo. Gracias a esto, podrás hacer que dos jugadores jueguen pero no a la vez. Para conseguir eso, es bastante más complicado, debido a que te introduces en el mundo de interrupciones, tareas y colas que son parte de sistemas operativos.

Otra opción que tienes, es usar la función kbhit() de la librería 'conio.h' la cual es muy recomendada para entradas y salidas.

Espero te sirva,